# Capturing packets from Android VPNService and transfer them over sockets to proxy server

Tags: android, sockets, networking, proxy, packets

Intention is to intercept all the traffic from the android device. I did this previously by creating a local proxy server and manually adding it in the wifi settings of the device. But now to avoid that we need that settings need not be changed and packets get intercepted automatically. For this purpose I employed AndroidVpnService, using this I am able to capture the packets but these are raw IP packets. I am not using the VPN tunnel since it seems it happens to support remote servers while I am having a local proxy server in place. Thus I am using simple JAVA sockets but the raw ip packets cannot be transmitted over these sockets especially due to difference in network layers at which they operate. Any suggestions on how can I make that happen or may be construct the suitable headers for transferring the packets over socket to connect to the internet and get the response back?